# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker "

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting this  There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker"  issue in my angular 8 project.

My code given below:

admin.module.ts:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        NgbModule
        ],
```

admin.component.html:

```
<input class="form-control " placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd " (click)="d.toggle() " name="dp " [(ngModel)]="model " [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true} " ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker ">
```

Error:

```
   core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
    There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker " ("="d.toggle() " name="dp " [(ngModel)]="model " [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true} " ngbDatepicker [ERROR ->]#d="ngbDatepicker ">
```

How to avoid this error?

Comment: the code looks fine to me, you could try restarting the build/serve process and/or restarting your PC

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that ALL of your attributes in HTML have an extra space before the closing quote. Try changing `#d="ngbDatepicker "` to `#d="ngbDatepicker"`.

Comment: @hlfrmn:  You know any html code formater vs code plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I use a different editor, so no idea.